# Associating segment with an absolute date and time (equivalent of PROGRAM-DATE-TIME for DASH)

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

HLS offers the [EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#page-15) tag that

> associates the first sample of a
> Media Segment with an absolute date and/or time

What is the equivalent of `PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` for MPEG-DASH?

I looked into `mpeg-dash events` but they associate arbitrary metadata to a period of time. What I need is to associated time to a segment.

I looked into `mpeg-dash descriptors` but as far as I could understand from the spec they associate metadata to a `period`/`adaption-set`. Things like audio configuration, frame packing, drm protection. I don't think descriptors can associate metadata with a specific segment (by segment I mean an element described by the `<S>` tag in the MPD).

I know that `PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` falls into the more general category of associating arbitrary metadata with a segment so I looked into the segment description in the MPEG-DASH spec (5.3.9.6.3 in ISO/IEC 23009-1) and I noticed that in addition to `"t"`, `"d"` and `"r"` any other other attribute can also be specified. But the spec doesn't say a word on the meaning or format of these additional attributes. I guess they are left to the application. But still I am wondering if there is any standardized name for specifying an absolute date and time?

Answer (score 0):

presentationTimeOffset is the DASH equivalent to PDT
https://dashif-documents.azurewebsites.net/DASH-IF-IOP/master/DASH-IF-IOP.html#timing-sampletimeline